# own std::is_function implementation

Tags: c++, stl

It's suggested [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) to be implemented in a following way:

```
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)const> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)volatile> : std::true_type {};
```

But is it a valid function syntax? Visual Studio 2013 gives an error:

```
error C2270: 'abstract declarator' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
```

Comment: Have you tried the code in an online compiler that uses gcc/clang? VS2013 has issues with variadic templates. It's possible that your code is correct and that the bug is in the compiler.

Comment: @Borgleader I checked it on IdeOne.com and you were right, it's VS issue. But still, is there any example of function with such signature? Why `const` and `volatile` can be put to non-member functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `const` or `volatile` after the function parameters is called a cv-qualifier-seq.
Section 8.3.5 paragraph 6 of the C++14 standard says:

> A function type with a cv-qualifier-seq or a ref-qualifier (including
>   a type named by typedef-name (7.1.3,14.1)) shall appear only as:
>
> — the function type for a non-static member function,
>
> — the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
>
> — the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or alias-declaration,
>
> — the type-id in the default argument of a type-parameter (14.1), or
>
> — the type-id of a template-argument for a type-parameter (14.3.1).

In your example, `Ret(Args...)const` and `Ret(Args...)volatile` satisfy the last case.

Comment: There's even an example in C++11's /10 (has moved to /6 in C++14, I think). You beat me by 10 s :)

Comment: @dyp: Nice.  I'm sure you'll get me next time.

Comment: There's actually very little that you can do with cv or ref qualifiers on non-member functions. They're legal, but pretty much useless. You can't declare a function that has them. You can't create a pointer to such a function.