# What is the meaning of ellipses in a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, variadic-functions

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Test
{
    int a;
    Test() : a(3)
    { }
    Test(const Test& t...)
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy constructor called\n";
        a=t.a;
    }
    int get_a()
    {
        return a;
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destructor is called\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test t;
    Test* t1=new Test(t);
    std::cout<<t.get_a()<<'\n';
    std::cout<<t1->get_a()<<'\n';
    delete t1;
}
```

Closely observe the three dots in parameter of copy constructor
I was really surprised when I tried this program. What is the use of it? What does it mean?

What the language specification says about this?

I know that three dots are used to represent variable length arguments in variadic functions 
like `printf()` and `scanf()` etc and also variadic macros introduced by C99. In C++, if I am not wrong, they are used in variadic templates.
Is this code well formed? Is this variadic copy constructor that can take any number of arguments?

It compiles & runs fine on g++ 4.8.1 & MSVS 2010.

Comment: Same as `Test(const Test& t, ...)` (note the comma)

Comment: Any constructor that can be called with one value of the type itself and takes it by reference is a possible copy constructor. The fact that optional further arguments may be supplied is immaterial.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: So, why comma is not necessary?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I think the language spec explicitly allows this. I'm not sure *why* they explicitly allow this, but they do.

Comment: I updated my answer, explaining what an abstract-declarator is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The draft standard in section `8.3.5` *[dcl.fct]* says `, ...` is synonymous with `...` unless `...` is part of abstract-declarator (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]If the parameter-declaration-clause terminates with an ellipsis
>   or a function parameter pack (14.5.3), the number of arguments shall
>   be equal to or greater than the number of parameters that do not have
>   a default argument and are not function parameter packs. **Where
>   syntactically correct and where “...” is not part of an
>   abstract-declarator, “, ...” is synonymous with “...”**.[...]

So it is a [variadic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657883/1708801) and as far as I can tell without additional arguments this is also a valid copy constructor, from section `12.8` *[class.copy]*:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its
>   first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile
>   X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other
>   parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

and this note says that ellipses are not parameters:

> ```
> void g(int = 0, ...); // OK, ellipsis is not a parameter so it can follow
>                       // a parameter with a default argument
> ```

which is backed up by the normative text above which says:

> If the parameter-declaration-clause terminates with an ellipsis[...]

Note, since it was asked an *abstract-declarator* is a declarator without an identifier.

Comment: Note the first rule I quote is what allows for the [infamous six dots](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33502576/1708801).

Answer (score 5):

> What is the use of it? What does it mean?

Yes, it introduces a variadic function.

> In C++ If I am not wrong they are used in variadic templates.

The syntax and semantics are different. It's a "C-style" variadic function, not a variadic *template* function. A copy constructor, moreover, cannot be a template function.

> A **non-template** constructor for class X is a **copy constructor** if its
>    first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile
>    X&, and either **there are no other parameters** or else all other
>    parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

Per §12.8.2 in the final draft (emphasis mine)

> Is this code well formed? Is this variadic copy constructor that can take any number of arguments?

If the ellipsis contains parameters, it is no more a copy constructor but a simple constructor. If there aren't, then it is a valid copy constructor.

```
 X(const X&, int = 1, double = 5); // copy-ctor
 X(const X&, int = 1, double); // constructor
```

Comment: So can I say that the progam in this link doesn't have copy constrctor because it uses no default arguments. http://ideone.com/VuNTU5