# C++ variadic function syntax

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-functions

In the C++03 standard, [dcl.fct] p.2 states that:

> The parameter-declaration-clause determines the arguments that can be specified, and their processing, when the func- tion is called. [ Note: the parameter-declaration-clause is used to convert the arguments specified on the function call; see5.2.2. —endnote]Iftheparameter-declaration-clauseisempty,thefunctiontakesnoarguments.Theparameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list. Except for this special case, void shall not be a parameter type (though types derived from void, such as void*, can). If the parameter-declaration-clause terminates with an ellipsis, the number of arguments shall be equal to or greater than the number of parameters that do not have a default argument. **Where syntactically correct, “, ...” is synonymous with “...”**.

The grammar for a `parameter-declaration-clause` allows it to end in either `...` or `, ...`. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35708014) and the answers said that initially the grammar allowed only `...`, and the comma variant (`, ...`) was introduced for compatibility with C.

My question is why does the quoted paragraph say "where syntactically correct"? Considering that `function parameter packs` or `pack expansions` were not present in C++03, are there any cases where it would be "syntactically incorrect" to consider `...` synonymous with `, ...`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for my understanding, it just mean that when you use `,...` with a correct syntax, then it can be replaced by `...`
for instance :

- `int printf(const char*, ...);` is a correct syntax and can be replaced by `int printf(const char*...);`
- `int printf(,...);` is not syntactically correct and is not equivalent to  `int printf(...);`

You can easily try in a C code by just adding the following prototypes:

- `void printf(...);` --> works
- `void printf(,...);` --> expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that your example is the case that the wording is trying to cover.

Comment: Just a quick comment, in the first sentence of your answer, shouldn't `...` and `, ...` be swapped?

Answer (score 0):

> are there any cases where it would be "syntactically incorrect" to consider ... synonymous with , ...?

Exactly as Guillaume says, it would be "syntactically incorrect" to rewrite

```
foo(...)
```

as

```
foo(, ...)
```

so that clause just handles the corner case where there is no prior parameter from which the ellipsis can be separated by a comma.